# Type alias circularly references itself

Tags: typescript

Why does this work:

```
type Foo = { x: Foo }
```

but this doesn't:

```
type Bar<A> = { x: A }
type Foo = Bar<Foo>
//   ^^^ Type alias 'Foo' circularly references itself
```

Shouldn't they be equivalent?

Comment: Check https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14174

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Per the documentation, a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) can refer to itself in a property, but not anywhere else on the right side of the declaration:

> > We can also have a type alias refer to itself in a property

So, as you noted, this works:

```
type Foo = { x: Foo }
```

> > However, it’s not possible for a type alias to appear anywhere else on the right side of the declaration

But this fails:

```
type Foo = Bar<Foo>
```

Comment: thanks to this I actually solved it using an interface...
I had `type Foo = Record<string, string | Foo>` and I had the error,
solved with `interface Foo { [key: string]: string | Foo }`.
I still think there should be no difference, but it's ok for me...

Comment: *"a type alias can refer to itself in a property, but not anywhere else on the right side of the declaration"* -- Apparently, that is **false**, since this works:
`type ItemType = string;` `type CollapsableItemType = (ItemType | CollapsableItemType)[];`. It also says at the place you linked to that the page is **deprecated**.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Thanks. It is good to know they changed that. I'll note that in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the second fails even if you don't use the constraint:

```
type Bar<A> = { x: string }
type Foo = Bar<Foo> // still fails with the same message
```

Basically, it the 2nd form needs to be this:

```
type Bar = { x: Foo }
type Foo = Bar;
```

To be equivalent to the first one.

Also, with `strictNullChecks` I'm pretty sure that there's no way to initialize such a type.

Comment: i have to say its very weird 

`type Test=string |Record<string,Test> // doesnt work `
but 
`type Test=string | {
 [Key: string | number]: Test
}`
works lol

Comment: @jonathanHeindl especially since Record is basically an alias for `{[key: string]: Test}` lol, the mysteries of typescript run deep

Answer (score 0):

As per jonathan's comment, this oddly works:

```
type Test = { [Key: string]: Test }
```