# How can i avoid circular references in type aliases

Tags: typescript, types

I have an array with elements that are either an array themselves (recursively) or a string.
I tried to write a type definition for this but the compiler complains about a circular reference

My question: How can I write a type alias like this without an error about circular referencing:

```
type Foo = Array<Foo | string>
```

the problem is described here: [Type alias circularly references itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352858/type-alias-circularly-references-itself)
but it doesn't help me in finding a solution for my problem

Comment: What's that meant to mean? ...why?

Comment: @spender I added an alinea, does that make it more clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type aliases in TypeScript cannot be recursive (due to how type aliases are resolved -- their resolution is not deferred), unless the recursion happens at the property-level as given in [the examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) in the official documentation.

The workaround, as explained in [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3988#issuecomment-124185555), is to use an **interface** instead, as interfaces *can* have the recursive definition you seek:

```
interface Foo extends Array<Foo | string> { }
```