# Infinit nested types in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-types

I am trying to define a interface/type to match this data structure.

1. The leaf properties are type of { dataType: string }, for example "tags", "isRestricted", "city", "postalCode" etc.
2. The non-leaf properties have other non-leaf properties of leaf properties. For example, "organism", "collection", and "collectionAddress".

Can anyone help define an interface or type for this data structure?  Much appreciated for any help!

```
{
  "sample": {
    "tags": { "dataType": "string[]" },
    "isRestricted": { "dataType": "boolean" },
    "organism": {
      "sex": { "dataType": "string" },
      "collection": {
        "collectionDate": {"dateType": "date"},
        "collectionAddress": {
          "addressLine": { "dataType": "string" },
          "city": { "dataType": "string" },
          "postalCode": { "dataType": "string" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a recursive record of strings to `{ dataType: string }` or other records. It's tempting to use exactly that here:

```
type Leaves<T> = Record<string, T | Leaves<T>>;
```

but you'll get an error, "Type circularly references itself" (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352858/type-alias-circularly-references-itself)), so we'll have to expand it into a mapped type:

```
type Leaves<T> = { [K in string]: T | Leaves<T> };
```

You could then use it like this:

```
const data: Leaves<{ dataType: string }> = {
    sample: {
        tags: { dataType: "string[]" },
        isRestricted: { dataType: "boolean" },
        organism: {
            sex: { dataType: "string" },
            collection: {
                collectionDate: { dataType: "date" },
                collectionAddress: {
                    addressLine: { dataType: "string" },
                    city: { dataType: "string" },
                    postalCode: { dataType: "string" },
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhCGA3CBnAPAFQHxQLxQG8AoKUqAbQGkoBLAOyhWACd6BzAXQC4oMoAfWAmTpsAbiIBfCUQDGAezpMoAE3jB4POElRoCq9fAzgIPJqzpsoknPmJlG8ALZgANqcIkHZDWxQ99NQ1jSB4AInN2cg4w6wAaL29aFAAlVBYaWWAIFQCDYJNwgCN5eXd4OljJBKTSeWY2CpoUJwDE2tIUCAAPPKCjQqgIjMsqmo6yBVd3LJpFNonaqZngOboAEXUPQK2QjzCgiDGoAHoTqFAweShZeABXNgALYABCdsXSZYhZxQBBFRUzFQ-k8Hwm8ABQJQKBg9G2+QGoSGkVG8XeYMmNFAfUMe3CKLYY3RGKgVyY8FcAGF5Cp4f08ciRoS0STSNVid52R0uWR2dIiEA)

---

It is important to note that this solution allows for things such as

```
{ dataType: { dataType: { dataType: "string" } } }
```

If you do not want this behavior, you may add another mapped type to map all the keys of `T` to `never`:

```
type Leaves<T> = { [K in string]: T | Leaves<T> } & { [K in keyof T]?: never };
```

Then in the previous snippet, you will get an error on the first `dataType` saying that `{ ... }` is not assignable to type `string`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhCGA3CBnAPAFQHxQLxQG8AoKUqAbQGkoBLAOyhWACd6BzAXQC4oMoAfWAmTpsAbiIBfKADJCFavSgBrCCAD2AM14cA-DzoRkzKJIlEAxurpMoAE3jB4POElRoC9x-AzgIPJlY6NlMcfGIyRngAWzAAG39CEkiyJzYUHk8HJ19IHgAiQPZyDnzTABpklNoUACVUFhoLYAg7TK8cvwKAI3V1BPg6MslK6tJ1ZjZBmhRozKqx0hQIAA927J8uqELG4OHRxbIrOITmmmt5w7Hj0+BzugARR0Ss59zE-OyIfagAel+oKAwOooBZ4ABXNgAC2AAEIFldSDcIGdrABBOx2ZioDJJRGHeCY7EoFAwegvDqbPLbIp7CoI-FHGigdbed4FWlsfYMxlQYFMeBxADC6jsFI27PkEq2+WGFT+AM+bL8ZRmUDo6mAUEQgpodig8BQBpUah5hxGZsiFsW1rIFrMRCAA)